# Set JTable not editable

Tags: java, swing, jtable, tablemodel, abstracttablemodel

I want to make my table uneditable. I tried this but it doesn't work :

```
public MyModel model = new MyModel(); // Here i am declaring my model


import javax.swing.table.AbstractTableModel; // the other class for the model


public class MyModel extends AbstractTableModel {

    public boolean isCellEditable(){  
        return false;  
    }

    @Override
    public int getColumnCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public int getRowCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getValueAt(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }



}
```

But it gives me error when i am using this line : it says that the method is undefined for MyModel class

```
model.addRow(row);
```

Comment: *"it says that the method is undefined for MyModel class"* - Yes, that be because `AbstractTableModel` doesn't have a `addRow` method...

Answer (score 0):

I did it .

```
public DefaultTableModel model = new MyModel();


public class MyModel extends DefaultTableModel {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int column){  
        return false;  
    }
```